# Partition Strategy in Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Which partition strategy Kafka stream uses ? Can we change the partition strategy in Kafka Stream as we can change in normal Kafka Consumer

```
streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,Collections.singletonList(StickyAssignor.class));
```

makes no difference and always StreamsPartitionAssignor is used

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot set an partition assignor.

Kafka Streams has very specific requirements how partition assignment works and if not done correctly, incorrect result could be computed. Thus, it's not allowed to set a custom partitions assignor.

Comment: As I explained in jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8207, if node 1 which is processing partitions 1,2,3  goes down other nodes take over because of num.standby.replicas >1. Once node 1 comes back again it will take time to build up the state store data for new partitions in productions as we have a heavy local state store

Comment: Maybe. In general, if node1 comes back it should have already partial state and thus recovery should be quick. In any case, load balancing is favored over stickiness for this case. However, we are aware of those issues and there is WIP to fix this. Compare https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-441%3A+Smooth+Scaling+Out+for+Kafka+Streams